# Facebook Open Graph not returning field

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using the PHP SDK and the Javascript SDK in tandem to do logins on my site (which works fine).

My app only authorizes to get basic info, as well as email as you can see in this screen
[image]

However, when I call the information up using:

```
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
    //$user_profile[] needs name etc to insert into DB
    $fname = $user_profile['first_name'];
    $lname = $user_profile['last_name'];
    $email = $user_profile['email'];
```

I get back everything except for email .... any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to update the scope in my parameters. Seems like you will need it in both places.

```
          $params = array(
            'scope' => 'read_stream, friends_likes, email',
            'redirect_uri' => 'http://www.#######.com'
          );
```